# Observable prototype extended function broken after @angular update

Tags: angular, rxjs

In an Angular application, we extend the rxjs Observable prototype with a helper function, called "withBusy", allowing us to chain this helper function to Observables:

```
Observable.prototype.withBusy = function (busyMonitor) {
    // simplified implementation details
    return this.finally(function () {
       // simplified implementation details
    });
};

this.methodReturningObservable()
    .withBusy(this.busyMonitor)
    .subscribe(result => { alert(result); });
```

This implementation worked fine, until we updated the @angular NPM packages from version 4.4.6 to 5.2.6. Note that the rxjs package was at version 5.5.6 and was **not** updated.

After this update, the implementation works everywhere, *except* for a single case in which a mergeMap is performed:

```
  let result: Observable<string>;
  result = Observable.from([1, 2])
            .mergeMap((value, idx) => "" + value)
            .withBusy(this.busyMonitor); // -> withBusy is not a function

  result.subscribe(e => {
      console.log(e);
  });
```

Since the rxjs version was not updated, I have no idea why this code is broken now. Any ideas?

Thanks for your time,
Koen

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but given that you are using v5 of RxJs, have you considered using [pipeable operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md) instead? That will allow you to create the `withBusy` pipe without the need to extend the Observable prototype and may be less likely to break through upgrades.

Comment: @KoenJ any progress on it?